# Print without confirmation on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Is there a way to ignore the confirmation dialog box of chrome when press ctrl+p (Version 31.0.1650.63 m). I tried adding "--kiosk --kiosk-printing" flags to the end of the “Target:” field. But It gives an error msg.

"The name 'C\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk --kiosk-printing' specified int the target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are correct."

Any one can help?

Answer (score 15):

Check this and follow the steps:

1. Launch Chrome and check that the Chrome Version is at the latest version (18.0.1 or higher )
2. Type about:flags in the address bar and ensure that the Disable Print Preview flag is NOT enabled (Print preview must be enabled for Kiosk Printing to work)
3. Close the browser
4. Find the browser shortcut on your desk top, right click and select 'properties'
5. Append the following text to the end of the target field: --kiosk --kiosk-printing
6. Save, and launch Google Chrome. It should now load in full screen (kiosk) mode
7. The print preview will appear on your screen, but will instantly print a receipt to your default printer.

[Reference](http://support.vendhq.com/entries/21006382-Enable-kiosk-silent-printing-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows-Video-)

Comment: Whilst this *may* theoretically answer the question, [one should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: --kiosk-printing alone worked for me, no flag editing was necessary. Chrome version ~71

Comment: Not working in Chrome 95.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make edits to the target when Chrome is completely off, Chrome is not enough to close.

Open task manager, go to processes, find Chrome, end the process, then do your own edits, and when you open Chrome the way you want it to work.

So :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --disable-print-preview
```

Or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --kiosk-printing
```