# Send print to printer directly on window.print() in Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I know this is a bit old question, but I need to get rid of the print dialog box in my HTML page.
I am concerned about the browsers - Google Chrome and Firefox. I have achieved my requirement using a plugin known as '**Seamless Print**' for firefox. By using the plugin, I have been able to directly send the print to my printer.

The issue is with Google Chrome. I have read about '**kiosk-printing**' and '**disable-print-preview**' options that can be appended to the target field of the properties window of Google Chrome.
(eg: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-print-preview --kiosk --kiosk-printing`)

By doing that, I am getting a full screen window with no means to enter URLs. Is there a plugin like '**Seamless Print**' available for Google Chrome? How can I achieve the same solution in Google Chrome. Please help.

Comment: ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073959/print-without-confirmation-on-google-chrome/48190022#48190022